# Mostrar ubicacion cada 10 segundos en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Hola estoy realiando una app en la que cada 10 segundos la ubicacion aparesca en un diferente lugar del mapa, lo malo es que no me funciona y  al ejecutar el programa me aparecen todas las ubicaciones ya situadas en su lugar. pero yo quiero que cada que pasen 10 segundo  vayan colocandose una por una como si estuvieran moviendose.

este es mi codigo:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    for ( contador=1;contador<=10;contador++) {

            final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

               handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
            }
        }, EXECUTION_TIME);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obtenerLatLong(contador)).title("Mi Hogar").snippet("Municipio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(obtenerLatLong(contador), 17));

    }
}
```

alguna manera de poder realizarlo?

Comment: Tinee que ser asi? hay un metodo que se llama getLastLocation() que podria resolverlo de manera mas simple

Comment: no tengo problemas al obtener la localizacion, el problema es que no me  situa las ubicaciones respecto al tiempo, las hace de golpe todas.

Comment: Por eso, si usaras el metodo getLastLocation el te devuelve un location y lo podrias mostrar en tu mapa, sin necesidad del bucle

Comment: es que no tiene que ver con el bucle, no tengo problemas con eso, solo con la sincronizacion de tiempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inténtalo de esta forma,así podrás realizar el conteo de tus puntos mientras le das un determinado tiempo entre marcadores.

```
        final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;
    final Handler handler =   new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(contador <=10) {

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obtenerLatLong(contador )).title("Mi Hogar").snippet("Municipio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(obtenerLatLong(contador ), 17));
                contador ++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
            }

        }
    }, EXECUTION_TIME);
```

Comment: Genial, me funciono gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un if dentro de tu ciclo, validando que si llego al ultimo elemento te muestre el marker:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;
for ( contador=1;contador<=10;contador++) {

        final long EXECUTION_TIME = 10000;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

           handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
        }
    }, EXECUTION_TIME);

    if(contador ==10){
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(obtenerLatLong(contador)).title("Mi Hogar").snippet("Municipio").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(obtenerLatLong(contador), 17));

   }

}
```

}

Comment: presiento que no entendiste el problema, el if no me soluciona nada estimado

Answer (score 0):

Solución

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService

Ejemplo:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;

class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
     public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
    };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
      scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
      scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
    }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
  }
```

El control del numero de ubicaciones que se quieren mostrar deben ir en un contador que no sea un bucle.

Comment: ¿Aquí donde se muestra la ubicación? sería bueno agregar esa parte del código.